# Align an image within a <td> without it having to be a background

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

I'm trying to create a list of products using a `<table>` since it's basically a table with rows and columns.

I want to have one of the columns list whether the item status is available or unavailable, and I'd like to represent this with a little green icon if available, red if otherwise. I also want that icon to be clickable to change it.

So I Googled and found I might be able to position it if it's a background image, but I want it clickable, so that's no good.

I've tried all the vertical aligns and centers etc.. that I've read and tried margins and padding and all sorts but I can't get my little icon image to be in the middle (horiz and vert) of my little `<td>`.

To clear something up:

I just want to know how to align the image within the `<td>`. The image itself is the anchor, when its clicked, the page reloads and the icon chanages. I've tried positioning this image within the `<td>` but can't. That's my question: How to position it?

Comment: This is many concepts rolled into one, and too broad of a question for SO.  You will need an anchor for the clickable link, AJAX (or something similar) to make the icon change etc.

Comment: No - I just want to know how to align the image within the <td>. The image itself is the anchor, when its clicked, the page reloads and the icon chanages. I've tried positioning this image within the <td> but can't. Thats my question, how to position it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are having difficulty aligning your image within the table cell. Tables contain many helpful properties that help with alignment. Here's an example table with images aligned to the center of the table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/Puppies4Life/zka5Q/

Comment: I think, this solves it. Or at least it proves it should work so! Thanks so much. I think maybe I need to stop staring at code for a while! Phew!

Answer (score 1):

First of tables should only be used for data and a list of products isn't data. I'd recommend using either plain old divs or a UL with lots of floated LI elements.

For your icon it would probably be best to make it an 'A' tag and either have the icon sitting as an image in the 'A' tag or have it as a background to the 'A' tag.

To align it horizontally make it's parent container text-align:center.

I'll assume that each product is going to be an image and be a set height? If so then to align it vertically simply make the padding-top of the container the correct height to set it in the center.

Hopefully the above will work for you :)

Comment: +1 I agree, maybe you should look at using something like 960.gs so you do not need to think so much about layout just give your divs names etc.